# Read and analyze text files containing both numbers and letters on the same line

Tags: java

I'm given a task to read data from a text file and save it to a Set. Text file represents an imaginary bill containing certain item description and it's price, quantity and total sum. I only need item's name and price. Text file looks like this:

```
Item_name   Item_price(float value with comma as format symbol)  Quantity(int)  Total(float)
Item_name   Item_price(float value with comma as format symbol)  Quantity(int)  Total(float)
```

(Text file contains multiple items). Also, items sometimes have numbers in their name, eg. LG 4k TV 1000U).

I tried to solve it like this:

```
private void readAndSave(Path file) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.toString()))))) {


        Set<Item> items = new TreeSet<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


            float price = 0, numb;
            boolean priceFound = false;
            String name = "";
            String[] lineElements;
            lineElements = line.split(" ");

            for(String temp: lineElements) {
                if((numb = getNumberRepresentation(temp)) != -1) {
                    if(!priceFound) {
                        price = numb;
                        priceFound = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                name += temp + " ";
            }
            items.add(new Item(name, price));

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while opening/writing files!");
    }

}
```

Class `Item` contains two variables(String, float) representing name and price of an item and extends `Comparable`.

And here is `getNumberRepresentation` method

```
private float getNumberRepresentation(String temp) {
    try {

        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
        format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        return format.parse(temp).floatValue();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the logic that, if a price is found, then the name must also be already found and all other Strings from the line can be skipped. Problem here is that sometimes I get a number from an item's name as price(1000U, from previous example). Is there a better and more efficient solution to this problem?

**Edit: File sample**

`Escape from Paradise City                                   70,00  1135   79450,00 
 Sony ITC60, TV cabel                                      111,26   111    12349,86`

Comment: One suggestion to your existing code... dont use 'try, catch' to parse you temp valiable... you should use TryParse()
e.g.
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (result)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
         }
         else
         {
//            if (value == null) value = ""; 
            Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                               value == null ? "<null>" : value);
         }

Comment: Do you have control over what the text file looks like. i.e. Can you make the file TAB delimited, then you are splitting on a TAB not a " " (space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately i don't have any control over the text file.

Comment: LOL sorry I just realised you are working in Java not c# :)

Comment: Please add to the question a sample of the file lines if possible.

Comment: Edit completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and get everything before the match of a Regex for the cost and the match of the regex for the cost.  I assume there won't be anything in the name that looks like ###,## where # are numerals. (Represented by \d in regex).

The tutorial can be found [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

It would look something like this:

Before reading the lines:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?) (\\d*,\\d*)");
```

For each line:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.matches() && m.groupCount() == 2) {
    name = m.group(1);
    price = getNumberRepresentation(m.group(2));
} else {
    // line doesn't match the pattern, handle the exception!
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use your approach(assuming that I understood  it correctly), but for name it gets everything before the sum and for the price it gets the sum. Here is the code:
 ` lineElements = line.split(" ");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches() && m.groupCount() == 2) {
        name = m.group(0);
       price = getNumberRepresentation(m.group(1));
    } else {
     System.out.println("Line error.");
    } `

Comment: I realize now that my explanation is written poorly.. instead of saying before splitting the lines, I should have said before reading and for each line.. I'll fix the answer to reflect this.  Also.. make sure your pattern is non-greedy.  ".*?" instead of ".*".  The first version of this answer was greedy which would give you the behavior you are talking about.